# My delete button stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As I was building the app I get this error.

```
Unknown action

The action 'destroy' could not be found for UsersController
```

The problem I have is that I do have a destroy method in my users controller and the button was working just fine. It just decided to stop working all of a sudden.

I started coding in a mailer and that is when it stopped working. Let me know what code you would like to see.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that web server restart didnt help...
Maybe you should check your routes... Do you have

```
resources :users
```

in routes.rb file? If so, could you show us the whole content of that file?

Comment: I do. I actually ended up having an extra end in my controller that closed the controller before the destroy action. Wasted a couple of hours on it. >_<

Comment: Yeah, these things happen. I suggest some syntax highlighting, e.g. the rails.vim plugin , if you are on Linux and Vim - very useful.

Comment: @SakoKassabian at the end of your users controller?  I'm having the same error and can't figure it out.